# Powershell Regex Multiline Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to regex a file. I have tried these but I'm not good with regex.

- `((\|\n.*|\n))\d.*\n\s.*[0-9]{1,3}\s`
- `((\|\n.*|\n))\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\n\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s[0-9]{1,3}\s`
- `((\|\n.*|\n))\d{7,8}\n\s.*[0-9]{1,3}\s`
- `\|\n\s.*\d{7}\n\s.*[0-9]{1,3}\s`
- `^.*\|\r?\n.*\r?\n[0-9]{1,3}$`

I have a file that has lines like these

```
  $00.00|0.00|0.00|||
  8360657
  68694
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out is the 3rd line is between 1 and 3 digits. If it's longer than 3 digits I don't care about it.

There is a lot more data in this file, and for each occurance of the above 3 lines I want to know all matches if the 3rd line in my example is 3 digits or less. How can I modify my regex to work?

Here is my example code of what I've tried:

```
$file = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\del2\file.le"
$content = gc $file -raw
$gRegex = "((\|\n.*|\n))\d{7,8}\n\s.*[0-9]{1,3}\s"
$content -match $guarantorRegex
```

I have got these to match using regex101.com however I'm not getting this to work in powershell...

---

**What worked for me in the end:**

```
$file = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\del2\D2341202.le"
$content = gc $file -raw
$guarantorRegex = "\|\r?\n[ ]{10}.*\r?\n[ ]{10}[0-9]{1,3}\s"
$content | select-string -Pattern $gRegex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > "C:\Users\user\Desktop\matches.txt"
```

Comment: Is your code going to always match those three lines *exactly* as they are? With whitespace as well? What is going to be consistent between the three line occurrences, and what may differ?

Comment: Try `^.*\|\r?\n.*\r?\n[0-9]{1,3}$` https://regex101.com/r/lttbzU/1

Comment: There are 10 spaces preceeding all lines

Comment: At regex101.com, all line endings are `\n`, your file must have Windows line endings, CRLF.

Comment: Then perhaps like `^[ ]{10}.*\|\r?\n[ ]{10}.*\r?\n[ ]{10}[0-9]{1,3}$` https://regex101.com/r/1w8BJP/1

Comment: Wiktor, do you mean use `n instead of \n for example? Bird, that works on regex101 but not in my powershell

Comment: think I got it modifying bird's suggestion `\|\r?\n[ ]{10}.*\r?\n[ ]{10}[0-9]{1,3}\s`

Comment: I think it should work [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%5b+%5d%7b10%7d.*%5c%7c%5cr%3f%5cn%5b+%5d%7b10%7d.*%5cr%3f%5cn%5b+%5d%7b10%7d%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c3%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=++++++++++%2400.00%7c0.00%7c0.00%7c%7c%7c%0d%0a++++++++++8360657%0d%0a++++++++++68694%0d%0a++++++++++%2400.00%7c0.00%7c0.00%7c%7c%7c%0d%0a++++++++++8360657%0d%0a++++++++++686%0d%0a++++++++++%2400.00%7c0.00%7c0.00%7c%7c%7c%0d%0a++++++++++8360657%0d%0a++++++++++68694%0d%0a). Perhaps with the multiline inline modifier  `(?m)^[ ]{10}.*\|\r?\n[ ]{10}.*\r?\n[ ]{10}[0-9]{1,3}\$`

Comment: What's the terminating `\s` for? That's matching a space - if you might have spaces at the end, then use `\s?` or `\s+`. The `$` is matching the end of string. I've condensed the original solution a bit, and added brackets so you can extract the matching digits with `S1` - `(?m)^\s{10}.*\|\r?\n\s{10}.*\r?\n\s{10}(\d{1,3})$`

Comment: I used the \s on the end to determine if the number continues (which I can probably do a better way) There really is not space there, just a \n actually but it worked so I just went with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match 10 spaces, you could match a space with a quantifier `[ ]{10}`

<sup>(The square brackets are for clarity only)</sup>

```
(?m)^[ ]{10}.*\|\r?\n[ ]{10}.*\r?\n[ ]{10}[0-9]{1,3}\$
```

- `(?m)` Inline modifier to enable multiline
- `^` Start of line
- `[ ]{10}.*\|` Match 10 spaces, 1+ times any char except a newline and `|`
- `\r?\n[ ]{10}.*` Match a newline, 10 spaces, 1+ times any char except a newline
- `\r?\n[ ]{10}[0-9]{1,3}` Match a newline, 10 spaces 3 digits 0-9
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%5b+%5d%7b10%7d.%2A%5c%7c%5cr%3f%5cn%5b+%5d%7b10%7d.%2A%5cr%3f%5cn%5b+%5d%7b10%7d%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c3%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=++++++++++%2400.00%7c0.00%7c0.00%7c%7c%7c%0d%0a++++++++++8360657%0d%0a++++++++++68694%0d%0a++++++++++%2400.00%7c0.00%7c0.00%7c%7c%7c%0d%0a++++++++++8360657%0d%0a++++++++++686%0d%0a++++++++++%2400.00%7c0.00%7c0.00%7c%7c%7c%0d%0a++++++++++8360657%0d%0a++++++++++68694%0d%0a)

Note that `\s` will also match a newline.

If you want to match whitespaces except a newline you could use `[^\S\r\n]{10}`

---

If you don't want to use anchors and there is a whitespace char at the end, you could use the pattern that worked for you

```
\|\r?\n[ ]{10}.*\r?\n[ ]{10}[0-9]{1,3}\s
```